# Cardinality of a quotient set $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}/\sim$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, set-theory, cardinals, equivalence-relations

I'm having trouble with the following task:

On the set of all functions $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ an equivalence relation $\sim$ is defined in the following way:

$f \sim g \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. f(f(n)) = g(g(n))$.

Prove that the quotient set $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}/\sim$ is uncountable.

I've tried to find an injective function from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}/\sim$ and I've tried proving that every equivalence class has only one element, but I haven't succeeded in either of the attempts. I can't even figure out what would be the main idea needed for the proof.

Comment: My approach would be to find some values for $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ over a finite range of $n$ that makes them distinct under the relation.  Then divide the naturals into countably many sets of the size of your range.  You can use any binary string to choose $f$ or $g$ behavior over each set, so you have found uncountably many distinct classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each $A\subseteq\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1\}$ let

$$f_A:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }n\in A\cup\{0\}\\
1,&\text{otherwise;}
\end{cases}$$

then $f_A\circ f_A=f_A$, so the function

$$\varphi:\wp(\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1\})\to{^{\Bbb N}\Bbb N}/\!\sim\;:A\mapsto[f_A]_\sim$$

is an injection.

Comment: Why did you write $^{\Bbb N}\Bbb N$ instead of $\Bbb{N}^{\Bbb{N}}$?

Comment: @manooooh: Because ${^A}B$ is a standard (if probably less familiar) notation for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$, and I prefer it when I want to emphasize that I’m thinking of the functions as functions and not as points in a Cartesian product.